# How do I write a service layer specification?

Tags: javascript, api, rest, specifications

I'm currently building a frontend prototype for a web application, and soon the backend programmers are going to start building the service layer. They've asked me to write a simple specification of the data formats I want from the various services along with possible parameters etc.

Are there any standard way of writing or structuring such specs? Can anyone give an example?

PS: All the service requests will be done in Javascript asynchronously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write an [SDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_document) together with the backend crew.

> A design document needs to be a stable reference, outlining all parts of the software and how they will work. The document is commanded to give a fairly complete description, while maintaining a high-level view of the software.

- Define the data. Whatever data your application processes ( client and the server ).
- Define the architecture. As you mentioned, you are making HTTP calls from client to server using asynchronic Javascript.
- Define the interfaces. Once you have a common understanding on data and architecture, the interfaces are much easier to put together. Interface descriptions usually describe all functions (with a short description, parameters and return values). If you want an example of RESTful interface description, take a look at [enStratus](http://es-content.s3.amazonaws.com/Enstratius_API_2012-04-12.pdf) document.

Use lots of pictures and examples to make the document *readable*. Don't make it too long: K.I.S.S !